# My code in Python is not replacing the string contents. Some of the letters seem to be missed

Tags: python, string, replace

My code in Python is not replacing the string contents. Some of the letters seem to be missed. The output is

['x', 'y', 'p', 's', 'v', 'r', 'p', 'u', 'n', 'p']

['c', 'b', 'k', 'h', 'e', 'i', 'k', 'f', 'm', 'k']

but it seems .replace should be putting it back the way it was in the first place.

```
message = "cypherpunk"

new_message = []

for letter in message:
    x = letter.replace("z","a").replace("y","b").replace("x","c").replace("w","d").replace("v","e").replace("u","f").replace("t","g").replace("s","h").replace("r","i").replace("q","j").replace("p","k").replace("o","l").replace("n","m").replace("m","n").replace("l","o").replace("k","p").replace("j","q").replace("i","r").replace("h","s").replace("g","t").replace("f","u").replace("e","v").replace("d","w").replace("c","x").replace("b","y").replace("a","z").replace("#","!")
    new_message.append(x)
    print(x)

print(new_message)

decode = []

for letter in new_message:
    x = letter.replace("a","z").replace("b","y").replace("c","x").replace("d","w").replace("e","v").replace("f","u").replace("g","t").replace("h","s").replace("i","r").replace("j","q").replace("k","p").replace("l","o").replace("m","n").replace("n","m").replace("o","l").replace("p","k").replace("q","j").replace("r","i").replace("s","h").replace("t","g").replace("u","f").replace("v","e").replace("w","d").replace("x","c").replace("y","b").replace("z","a").replace("!","#")
    decode.append(x)

print(decode)
```

Comment: A dictionary would be a better way to do all those `replace()` calls in one step.

Comment: Can you tell how you are planning to "encrypt" the string? You have got a whole lot of ```.replace()```

Comment: `.replace("n","m").replace("m","n")` does not make sense, there will be no `m`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're doing another replacement on the result of each preceding replacement. As a simple example, if you had:

```
message = "a"
x = message.replace("a", "z").replace("z", "a")
print(x)
```

this would print `a` because it first translates `a` to `z`, then it translates `z` to `a`. On the other hand,

```
message = "a"
x = message.replace("z", "a").replace("a", "z")
print(x)
```

will print `z` because the first replacement doesn't do anything (there's no `z` in z), so only the second replacement is effective.

Since you're doing the replacements in reverse alphabetic order during encoding, any letter that gets translated to an earlier letter in the alphabet gets translated back to itself. And during decoding, it's the opposite.

Instead of doing multiple calls to replace, use a dictionary with the translations:

```
encode_dict = {"a": "z", "b": "y", ..., "#": "!"}
decode_dict = {"a": "z", "b": "y", ..., "!": "#"}

message = "cypherpunk"

new_message = []

for letter in message:
    x = encode_dict.get(letter, letter)
    new_message.append(x)

print(new_message)

decode = []

for letter in new_message:
    x = decode_dict.get(letter, letter)
    decode.append(x)

print(decode)
```